# Comparing two unsorted lists in linux, listing the unique in the second file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, comparison, grep

I have 2 files with a list of numbers (telephone numbers).

I'm looking for a method of listing the numbers in the second file that is not present in the first file.

I've tried the various methods with:

```
comm (getting some weird sorting errors)
fgrep -v -x -f second-file.txt first-file.txt (unsure of the result, there should be more)
```

Comment: Have you checked this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1617326/15165 ? BTW: before doing anything make sure you have got all the trailing lines and extra blank spaces removed. This could be the reason you have not found all of them...

Answer (score 90, accepted):

```
grep -Fxv -f first-file.txt second-file.txt
```

Basically looks for all lines in `second-file.txt` which don't match any line in `first-file.txt`. Might be slow if the files are large.

Also, once you sort the files (Use `sort -n` if they are numeric), then `comm` should also have worked. What error does it give? Try this:

```
comm -23 second-file-sorted.txt first-file-sorted.txt
```

Comment: Seems to do the trick, Took only a couple of seconds, with about 500000 lines in the two files combined

Comment: Cool, 500k should be fine on modern machines. But I wouldn't have imagined it would be THAT fast..! Did the comm thing work?

Comment: Warning, you can't use sort -n with comm, see my test

Comment: The grep solution works only in the case, that `second-file.txt` is not empty.

Comment: what does the -23 flag mean?

Comment: According to the  [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/comm) -23 will output only 1 column instead of the default of 3. It will output only the the lines unique to second-file-sorted.txt

Comment: For those wondering how to do the opposite, just remove the -v (invert-match)

Comment: I tried the grep vs the comm on 2 large text files that were sorted unique and compared case-insensitive. Each file had only email addresses. The comm command did not find all the matches, but the grep command did. The grep command took considerably longer. The difference in results was not insignificant.

Answer (score 32):

You need to use `comm`:

```
comm -13 first.txt second.txt
```

will do the job.

ps. order of first and second file in command line matters.

also you may need to sort files before:

```
comm -13 <(sort first.txt) <(sort second.txt)
```

in case files are numerical add `-n` option to `sort`.

Comment: That results in:  comm: file 2 is not in sorted order
comm: file 1 is not in sorted order
And a list with exactly the same number of lines as file2

Comment: so you can try to sort them before. i've just added variant with `comm` + `sort`.

Comment: Keep in mind that sorting the files numerically may not work, as comm expects them to be sorted lexicographically.

Answer (score 14):

This should work

```
comm -13 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

It seems sort -n (numeric) cannot work with comm, which uses sort (alphanumeric) internally

f1.txt

```
1
2
21
50
```

f2.txt

```
1
3
21
50
```

21 should appear in third column

```
#WRONG
$ comm <(sort -n f1.txt) <(sort -n f2.txt)   
                1
2
21
        3
        21
                50

#OK
$ comm <(sort f1.txt) <(sort f2.txt)
                1
2
                21
        3
                50
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cat f1.txt f2.txt | sort |uniq > file3
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this provides the unique list of all lines in both files, and the requester is seeking only different lines from file 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two sorted files, `diff` was designed for this:

```bash
diff -y --suppress-common-lines --color=always sorted_list1.txt sorted_list2.txt | less
```