# Difference between two lists using Bash

Tags: bash, sorting, sed, awk, grep

Ok, I have two related lists on my linux box in text files:

```
 /tmp/oldList
 /tmp/newList
```

I need to compare these lists to see what lines got added and what lines got removed. I then need to loop over these lines and perform actions on them based on whether they were added or removed.

How do I do this in bash?

Comment: The same question was asked 4 days before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11099894/comparing-2-unsorted-lists-in-linux-listing-the-unique-in-the-second-file/11101143#11101143

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Use the `comm(1)` command to compare the two files. They both need to be sorted, which you can do beforehand if they are large, or you can do it inline with bash *process substitution*.

`comm` can take a combination of the flags `-1`, `-2` and `-3` indicating which file to suppress lines from (unique to file 1, unique to file 2 or common to both).

To get the lines only in the old file:

```
comm -23 <(sort /tmp/oldList) <(sort /tmp/newList)
```

To get the lines only in the new file:

```
comm -13 <(sort /tmp/oldList) <(sort /tmp/newList)
```

You can feed that into a `while read` loop to process each line:

```
while read old ; do
    ...do stuff with $old
done < <(comm -23 <(sort /tmp/oldList) <(sort /tmp/newList))
```

and similarly for the new lines.

Answer (score 9):

The [diff command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/diff) will do the comparing for you.

e.g.,

```
$ diff /tmp/oldList /tmp/newList
```

See the above man page link for more information. This should take care of your first part of your problem.

Comment: I'll just emphasize that the `diff` command has a ridiculous number of options for formatting the output, which could provide a convenient input to the program that will process the differences.

Comment: @chepner good point .. it's definitely worth checking out the linked man page.

Answer (score 5):

Consider using Ruby if your scripts need readability.

To get the lines only in the old file:

```
ruby -e "puts File.readlines('/tmp/oldList') - File.readlines('/tmp/newList')"
```

To get the lines only in the new file:

```
ruby -e "puts File.readlines('/tmp/newList') - File.readlines('/tmp/oldList')"
```

You can feed that into a while read loop to process each line:

```
while read old ; do
  ...do stuff with $old
done < ruby -e "puts File.readlines('/tmp/oldList') - File.readlines('/tmp/newList')"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is old, but for completeness we should say that if you have a really large set, the fastest solution would be to use diff to generate a script and then source it, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

line_added() {
   # code to be run for all lines added
   # $* is the line 
}

line_removed() {
   # code to be run for all lines removed
   # $* is the line 
}

line_same() {
   # code to be run for all lines at are the same
   # $* is the line 
}

cat /tmp/oldList | sort >/tmp/oldList.sorted
cat /tmp/newList | sort >/tmp/newList.sorted

diff >/tmp/diff_script.sh \
    --new-line-format="line_added %L" \
    --old-line-format="line_removed %L" \
    --unchanged-line-format="line_same %L" \
    /tmp/oldList.sorted /tmp/newList.sorted

source /tmp/diff_script.sh
```

Lines changed will appear as deleted and added. If you don't like this, you can use --changed-group-format. Check the diff manual page.

Answer (score 1):

I typically use:

```
diff /tmp/oldList /tmp/newList | grep -v "Common subdirectories"
```

The `grep -v` option inverts the match:

> -v, --invert-match
>                Selected lines are those not matching any of the specified pat-
>                terns.

So in this case it takes the `diff` results and omits those that are common.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `diff`

```
$ diff /tmp/oldList /tmp/newList

$ man diff
```